# Data structures in JDK, under what scenario which one to use?

Tags: java, data-structures

Does there exist a cheat sheet for data structure like TreeMap, SortedMap, HashSet etc and under what circumstances which one to use. Are there good articles you recommend

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Collections Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/TOC.html) is a good resource.

Answer (score 0):

Read a good [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201775786)! Datastructures are abstract and not bound to Java. Maybe this [website](http://nist.gov/dads/) is also worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Browsing through wikipedia's [list of data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures) will give some idea of how structures are used in general, and what the JDK has or hasn't got that's significant (Such as having linked hash set but not exposing what kind of tree the tree map is, and having a nice set of concurrent data structures).

Answer (score 0):

You will find a small [**"Java Collections Cheat Sheet"** here](http://www.surfscranton.com/Architecture/JavaCollections.htm).

The [Sun Collections overview](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html) is still the most complete quick reference out there.